# Does the amount of blood on Denji's body determine how much chainsaw will be released from Denji's body?

Tags: chainsaw-man

In *Chainsaw Man* S1E4, we saw only part of Chainsaw protruded from Denji's head and the blades on his hand didn't got released. Prior to that, Denji lost his right hand. He said he lost a lot of blood, hence the full devil parts was not activating. Is he referring to his own blood? If so, why does losing any of his blood won't fully activate the chainsaws as the devil powers are coming from Pochita?

Comment: I can't comment on the manga because I haven't read it yet, but in episode 7 of the anime Power says "Denji keeps losing blood. His chainsaw will retract if that continues." I'm not entirely sure what exactly you're asking in your question, but I thought this could be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume so in the anime. The manga prioritized the sole use of blood as a devil's form of healing (Unlike Power who specializes in blood). But seeing how Denji's chainsaws melt of him in the anime rather than scrap off into metal in the manga, I'd assume that detail is saying his chainsaws are made of blood.